# Ternary operator inside NavigationLink SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem when trying to user ternary operator on a button in NavigationLink. I have an array of campaigns, which is displayed in a carouselView. Bellow carousel there is a button(NavigationLink) for opening another view which displays details of the campaign. The array of campaigns is empty initially, so I have to check if self.cardCampaigns > 0, if that is true it should navigate to a view which displays details of the campaign, otherwise ignore( I am trying to show a view with text "No campaigns available". I am using ternary operator for that, but it's not working. I get "Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'CampaignDetailsView' and 'Text'" error where I use ternary operator.

My code is bellow:

```
NavigationLink(destination:
    self.cardCampaigns.count > 0 ? CampaignDetailsView(viewModel: CampaignDetailsViewModel(campaign: cardCampaigns[self.count].campaign)) : Text("No Campaign found")
) {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .foregroundColor(Color.orOrangeColor)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
        Text("Details")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the types of `CampaignDetailsView` and `Text` don't match. You need to use a `@ViewBuilder` (or just a `Group`, `VStack` etc).

Here is a solution with the destination view as a `@ViewBuilder` computed property:

```
@ViewBuilder
var destinationView: some View {
    if cardCampaigns.count > 0 {
        CampaignDetailsView(viewModel: CampaignDetailsViewModel(campaign: cardCampaigns[self.count].campaign))
    } else {
        Text("No Campaign found")
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: destinationView) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, I mean I knew it is because they didn't match but didn't know how to make them similar structs ( ViewBuilder , group or VStack) .